# C++: Counting total frames in a game

Tags: c++, memory-management, int, long-integer, increment

Not a very good title, but I didn't know what to name it.

Anyway, I am counting the total frames (so I can calculate an average FPS) in my game with a `long int`. Just in case the game went on reallly long, what should I do to make sure my `long int` doesn't get incremented past its limit? And what would happen if it did go past its limit?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need an average over the whole game? Why not just maintain the last second's/last few seconds' worth of counts and then not bother from there?

Comment: Isn't possible using something like long long long int?

Comment: @BlackBear yes, there is a `long long int`, but there would still be the "potential" for the same problem.

Comment: I believe that if you exceed the maximum value for an int, it will either wrap around to the largest negative number and work its way up, or just throw an exception.

Comment: Would you have more luck asking at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ? That's not rhetorical. I'm honestly wondering.

Comment: @Jake this question doesn't really actually have anything to do with games, but I didn't know how else to name it, and ask the question.

Comment: I am guessing what happens depends somewhat on your compiler and system. I would suggest setting the number at the max and then incrementing to see what happens.

Comment: @Jay: I don't think so. To overflow it you need 1169884834710 years playing at 30 frames per second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Average FPS throughout the length of an entire game doesn't seem to be a very useful statistic.  Typically you will wish to measure peaks and valleys, such as highest fps / lowest fps and amount of frames spent below and above threshold values.

In reality though, I would not worry.  Even if you were to just use a 32 bit unsigned int, your game could run at 60fps for 19884 hours before it would overflow.  You should be fine.

EDIT:

The best way to detect overflow in this case is to check and see if the integer decreased in value after being incremented.  If so, you could just keep another counter around which is the number of times you have overflowed.

Answer (score 8):

This problem is present for any kind of counters.

For your specific problem, I wouldn't worry.

A `long int` counts up to 2 billions (and more) in most worst cases (on 32 bit computers/consoles). Supposing your game is doing 1000 frames per second (which is a lot!), it would take 20000000 seconds to overflow your counter: more than 5000 hours, more than 231 days.

I'm pretty sure something else would cause your game to stop, if you try to run it for that long!

Comment: @peoro yes, I have done some calculations myself, but this is just in case. and what does happen when a counter gets over-incremented?

Comment: @Jay: If it's declared as unsigned, it'll go back to 0. If not, it'll become a negative number. The exact effects of this depend on your code.

Comment: @Jay: when an integer overflows (ie: it gets over the biggest value it can contain) it restarts from the smallest value it can contain. What happens depend on what operations you do on the integer, most likely your FPS indicator will show that your game is running at -X frames per second.

Comment: @luiscubal @peoro Signed overflow causes undefined behavior in C and C++. It is not guaranteed to wrap around to the most negative number. Unsigned overflow however is well-defined. See [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679047/integer-overflow-in-c-standards-and-compilers).

Answer (score 7):

I would instead consider using an e[xponentially-weighted moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average). That approach will kill two birds with one stone: it will avoid the problem of accumulating a large number, and it will also adapt to recent behavior so that an accumulated average of 100fps in the year 2010 would not skew the average so that a 2fps rate would seem acceptable for a month or so in 2011 :).

Answer (score 2):

If long int is 32-bits, the maximum value is 2^31-1, so with 1ms updates it will overflow in 24.9 days, not 231 [2^31/1000/60/60/24].

Hopefully not too OT... generally for games this may not really be an issue, but it is for other applications.  A common mistake to be careful of is doing something like

```
extern volatile uint32_t counter;
uint32_t one_second_elapsed = counter + 1000;
while ( counter < one_second_elapsed ) do_something();
```

If counter + 1000 overflows, then do_something() will not be called.  The way to check this is,

```
uint32_t start = counter;
while ( counter - start < 1000 ) do_something();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could actively check for an overflow in your arithmetic operations. E. g. [SafeInt](http://safeint.codeplex.com/) can do that for you. Of course, the performance is worse than for `i++`.

However, it is unlikely that a 32 bit integer will overflow if you always increment by one.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest something like this for this specific case. Other solutions to avoid an overflow could be to use bigger types to store the value: `long long`, or even dynamic-length integers offered by some advanced math libraries. But for this case it's not worth it, it would only make things slower, more complicated and in general _worse_ without any gain.

Comment: I agree - therefore I said that the performance will degrade. Perhaps I should add it will probably degrade significantly as using SafeInt will require a try-catch-block. But the question was how to detect overflows. For the specific case, I think we all agree that the problem is unlikely to happen and you should just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to use an average over a small number of frames.  You mentioned that you want to calculate an average, but there is really no reason to keep such a larger number of samples around to calculate an average.  Just keep a running total of frametimes over some small period of time (where small could be something between 10-50 frames - we typically use 16).  You can then use that total to calculate an average frames per second.  This method also helps smooth out frame time reports so that the numbers don't jump all over the place.  One thing to watch out for though is that if you average over too long of a time period, frame rate spikes become more "hidden", meaning it might be tougher to spot frames which cause framerate to drop if those frames only happen every so often.

Something like this would be totally sufficient I think (non-tested code to follow):

```
// setup some variables once
const int Max_samples = 16;    // keep at most 16 frametime samples
int FPS_Samples = 0;
int Current_sample = 0;
int Total_frametime = 0.0f;
float Frametimes[Max_samples];
for ( int i = 0; i < Max_samples; i++ ) {
    Frametimes[i] = 0.0f;
```

Then when you calculate your frametime, you could do something like this:

```
// current_frametime is the new frame time for this frame
Total_frametime -= Frametimes[Current_sample];
Total_frametime += current_frametime;
Frametimes[Current_sample] = current_frametime;
Current_sample = ( Current_sample + 1 ) % Max_samples;   // move to next element in array

Frames_per_second = Max_samples / Total_frametime;
```

It's a rough cut and could probably use some error checking, but it gives the general idea.